# How to compare two series on every point in Highchart?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have multiple series to display in HighcChart.

Example series

```
seriesOptions[0]=
{
 name: 'series1',
  data: [[1503550875000,23.93],[1503551525000,23.64],[1503552176000,23.46]]
};  

seriesOptions[1]=
{
name: 'series2',
  data: [[1503550865000,34.52],[1503551515000,34.64],[1503552166000,34.73]]
}
```

I need to compare both series on hover. Currently its compare only those points where date is same. I want to get approx point of other series when I `hover` on first series.

Comment: have you tried   
`tooltip: {  crosshairs: true,  shared: true  }`

Comment: @AhmedSunny I believe the point of the question is that, since the `x` values are not the same, that solution does not work. I don't think there is a straightforward solution, as you would have to define for the chart library what you mean by "approximate" point match. Someone may have a solution, but I would do this work in pre-processing, to standardize the `x` values between series.

Comment: right @jlbriggs, I got the solution for "x" value but I use my custom function to get that value . Now I need to update chart tooltip from custom function

Comment: Well, like I said, I would do this the other way around. If the `x` values are close enough to be compared, just standardize them in pre-processing so they're actually the same, and then the chart will do all of the work. Anything else is a lot of work to accomplish little. You can always provide the 'actual' `x` value as an additional node on the data point for reference if it's needed.